# How to call virtual functions of a derived class through base class pointers, assuming functions in base class are not virtual

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

```
class Base
{   
    public:
    virtual void f() 
    {
        g();
    }
    virtual void g()
    {
        cout<<"base";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{   
    public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        Base::f();
    } 
    virtual void g()
    {
        cout<<"derived";
    } 
};

int main()
{
    Base *pBase = new Derived;
    pBase->f();
    return 0;  
}
```

In this program I have kept both derived and base class functions as virtual. Is it possible call virtual functions of derived class through base class pointer and base class functions are not virtual.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: No it is not possible if the methods are not virtual in the base. But you could use `dynamic_cast` to attempt to convert to a derived pointer and then call them.

Comment: What lead you to the situation where you need this?

Comment: @wohlstad If functions are not virtual then base class won't be polymorphic and `dynamic_cast` won't  work.

Comment: @user7860670 good point. However - it will work if there are _any_ virtual methods, even if not necessarily the ones the OP need to call, right ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo this was usually done back in the days of C++03 for MMORPGs, back when most Engines and Networking are "In House". It's the Go to way to queue "Messages" from the client's which consist of Hundreds of Object Types, in Asia at least. I guess he's doing something similar?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it was an assignment :(

Comment: @wohlstad `if the methods are not virtual in the base` it is possible with type erasure. See my answer

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I might have missed something, but as long as you modify the base class and keep the derivation hierarchy,  I don't see the advantage of using type erasure over virtual methods. After all your implementation is emulating a v-table anyway so why not use the standard language mechanism ? Type erasure is usually useful when you want to de-couple the derived from it's potential base, but here you keep the hierarchy anyway.

Comment: @wohlstad at no point in my answer I have mentioned that type erasure with inheritance is better then inheritance itself. Usually one uses type erasure **not to inherit** (de-coupling, as you mentioned). What I did address, is the "impossibility" of calling derived methods from *non-virtual* base methods. Another way would be to use NVI.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik fair enough. Then I agree it is possible, but wouldn't recommend this method.

Comment: @wohlstad we know that the question is "from an assignment", so there's no real use case from the start. TBH, I wouldn't recomment using `dynamic_cast` either. It breaks the abstraction. Capturing `static_cast` within the base class itself breaks nothing (it doesn't reveal derived class to the base's caller). And more over, `static_cast` itself has no runtime overhead.

Comment: @AzrielElijay _"It's the Go to way to queue "Messages""_ - what is the go to way?  I don't see the connection to implementing any kind of message queue.

Comment: @iso42 So, you wonder how to get the call to `pBase->f();` to print `derived` if you make both `Base::f` and `Base::g` non-`virtual` even though `Derived::f` calls `Base::f`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'll try my best to butter down the concept since it's an old concept in MMORPGs. Say a Character send a Request which alters/access/read a Database entry, instead of processing Request in an independent queue, We create a Base class, with a virtual Method called `execute`. this way we can have an STL Container of the Base class and simply call `execute`. instead of creating a queue for each type of object, since most of this requests have different member objects. And there are a lot of them in most MMORPGs.

Comment: @AzrielElijay That part is how polymorphism has been used since the mid 80's which pre-dates MMORPGs with some 5-10 years at least. What doesn't make sense in this case is to have a non-polymorphic base and try to coerce calls to be made to a derived class' member functions (that happens to share the same names and signatures as the base class functions) using a base class pointer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Dang , I just re-read my first comment and I guess I Misunderstood his question at the time. But there was a time we used to omit the virtual keyword and create and simulate the VTables when things got large. But even for 98, it was completely unnecessary as the gain is not that much. and only made things much more complex than it really needs to be. Now that you mention it it's mind boggling.

Answer (score 1):

*assuming functions in base class are not virtual*
This can be achieved via type erasure. But there are caveats.
Your "base" class should decide between the two:

1. Being a view class (can't be called `delete` on or created by itself)
2. Being a resource owning class (implemented similar to 1, but stores a smart pointer).

Here is an example for case 1: https://godbolt.org/z/v5rTv3ac7

```
template <typename>
struct tag{};

class base
{
public:
    base() = delete;

    template <typename Derived>
    explicit base(tag<Derived> t)
        : _vTable(make_v_table(t)) 
    {}

    int foo() const { return _vTable.foo(*this); }

protected:
    ~base() = default;

private:
    struct v_table
    {
        virtual int foo(const base &b) const = 0;

    protected:
        ~v_table() = default;
    };

    template <typename Derived>
    static const v_table& make_v_table(tag<Derived>){
        struct : v_table 
        {
            int foo(const base &b) const {
                return static_cast<const Derived&>(b).foo();
            }
        } static const _vTable{};
        return _vTable;
    }

private:
    const v_table& _vTable;
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    explicit derived()
        : base(tag<derived>{})
    {}

    int foo() const { return 815; }
};

// example
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    derived d{};
    const base& b = d;
    std::cout << b.foo() << '\n';
}
```

Take notice, that you can only take a pointer or a reference (cv-qualified) to a base class. The base class can't be created on its own.
Also `tag<T>` is needed to call a templated constructor.

---

**DO NOT CALL DERIVED METHODS IN THE BASE CONSTRUCTOR OR DESTRUCTOR**

---

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is *no*, if the function you are calling is not `virtual`. The Compiler would have no Idea that you are trying to call a function from the Derived Class, and won't make and I'm paraphrasing here since I do not know the proper term for,"*Won't make proper entries in the Virtual Table*".

```
class Base
{   
    public:
    void f() 
    {
        std::cout<<"Base f() Called\n";
        g();
    }
    virtual void g()
    {
        std::cout<<"Base g()\n";
    }
    virtual ~Base(){std::cout<<"Base Destroyed\n";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{   
    public:
    void f()
    {
        g();
    } 
    virtual void g()
    {
        std::cout<<"Derived g()\n";
    } 
    ~Derived(){std::cout<<"Derived Destroyed\n";}
};

int main()
{
    Derived* D1 = new Derived();
    Base* B1 = D1;
    B1->f();
    delete B1;
    return 0;  
}
```

Have a look at the following code, I have not declared `Base::f()` as `virtual`,calling `B1->f()` calls the Base Method, but the base method calls a virtual function `Base::g()` and this allows the "Derived" method be called.

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005791/c-virtual-table-lookup-how-does-it-search-replace) or [this blogpost](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2017/06/10/understanding-virtual-tables/) to understand Virtual Tables.

**(1)** and you must **ALWAYS** declare the **destructor** of a base class `virtual` when **destroying** Derived Object through a Base Pointer, else the resources used by the Derived Object **will never get destroyed** and it's memory will leak until the program closes.

Don't Take my word as gospel, I am simply passing on knowledge I have acquired from first hand experience, Except for **(1)**, specially if you are not using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers)

Comment: Ok thanks! I did not knew about this memory leak issue would arise. I am pretty new to C++ moved from python, still learning!

Comment: @iso42, also don't forget to destroy an object via `delete` when creating it via `new` or `delete[]` when created using `new[]`. They are dynamically created and doesn't get destroyed when they go out of scope. I noticed that you haven't in your question's snippet.

Comment: yes, this is a sample snippet to make you guys understand my problem. Im not implementing this anywhere

Comment: And also I have a doubt. What is the concept behind accessing virtual functions of derived class through base class pointers?

Comment: @iso42 The Concept is called [polymorphism, you can read more about it here](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism) explaining the concept through a comment will not do the concept justice.

Comment: I am pretty new to cpp and OOPS. So this is an example of run time polymorphism right?